How do I allow google sheets checkbox to reference another cell and be optional at the same time?
I have a checkbox that is looking at another cell to automatically check if the other cells value is true. What I would like to do is if the other cell value is true, then the checkbox is locked "true", if the other cell value is "false" I would still like the option to check the checkbox regardless of the other cell value.
I am stuck and not sure what is the best way to accomplish what I'm after
Screenshot of Google Sheet Example

I would still like the option to check the checkbox regardless of the other cell value. This is not possible, but are there alternatives? The question describes an XY problem; that is, it asks about an attempted solution rather than the actual problem. It would be more helpful if the question described the scenario in which the "manual override" was required. This would enable users to consider how to solve the problem.
